# Python 3 pd.read_csv Columns (7) have mixed types. Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to load a data with Jupyter Noteebook Python 3.x but i got an error. I loaded same data with R, no problem.

Read csv command below;

reputation_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Seckin/Documents/Assignment/Data/reputation_data",sep="#",header=None,index_col=False)

Data sample;

79.146.219.54#1#2#Malicious Host#ES#Madrid#40.4165000916,-3.70260000229#3
79.22.246.22#1#3#Malicious Host#IT#Bertinoro#44.1487007141,12.1365003586#3
80.14.238.210#4#3#Malicious Host###44.1487007141,12.1365003586#3

Error;
C:\Users\Seckin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2698: DtypeWarning: Columns (7) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)